# rspec - what is the syntax of before :each and before :all vs let! and let

Tags: ruby, rspec, let

When can I use let or let! and how can I then refer to variables inside the test?

How does the usage of let and let! compare to using before :each and before :all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'classic' way of using `before(:each)` and `before(:all)` is

```
describe "tests" do
  before :each do
    @var1='a'
    @var2='b'
  end
end
```

You then refer to the instance variables by preceeding them with an `@` sign inside the tests, i.e.

```
describe "tests" do
  before :each do
    @var1='a'
    @var2='b'
  end
  it  "does stuff" do
    a=some_class.some_method(@var1)
    expect(a).to eq @var2
  end
end
```

If you want a variable to have the same value in each test you can use `before :all`.
If you want a variable to have the same value generated for each test use `before :each`.
Generally use `before :each` as improper use of `before :all` can too easily lead to intermittent test failures.
Think of `before :all` as defining constants.

The `let`/`let!` format looks like this:

```
describe "tests" do
  let(:var1)  {'a'}
  let!(:var2) {srand(25)}
  it  "does stuff" do
    a=some_class.some_method(var1)
    expect(a).to eq var2
  end
end
```

Notice several things:

1. `var1` and `var2` now look like local variables, i.e. `var1` *instead of* `@var1` when used in the test and setup.  In actual fact they are test class methods.  The important thing to note for usage is that you do *NOT* use the `@` sign when subsequently using them unlike the before `:each` and `before :all` where you did.
2. In the first case of the `let`'s example, `let` is used with `var1`.  This allow the memoization across examples to work.  In the second case `let!` is used with `var2`.  This is needed because you want the variable (method) to be called/set explicitly before each use.  `srand()` is a great example of when you would need this as it seeds the random number generator but only for the next use of `rand()` so if using it in multiple test examples resetting it is needed each time.

Comment: Just adding my two cents. I prefer to leave the `:each` out of my normal `before` statements. It just looks cleaner. Then add `:all` on the off chance that I make a `before(:all)` block. Another interesting find was you could mimic the `let` paradigm in `subject` lines, essentially namespacing nested subjects `subject(:call_some_method) { some_class.some_method(var1) }` so then the `it` block is a single line, and reads very well.

Comment: Both `let` and `let!` get re-evaluated every time, so your random number will be different each time irrespective of which one you use. The difference is when they are initialised. `let!` is initialised before all examples - even examples which don't use it. `let` is initialised the first time an example uses it.